# Why Image doesn't display?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a weather app that includes an ImageFrame and CurrentWeatherFrame. I am having issues getting ImageFrame to appear when I run my script. I am only seeing the CurrentWeatherFrame. Can someone help me figure out what is causing this issue?

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Weather import WeatherPredictions as wp

class ImageFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        os.chdir(r'C:\Users\milos\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\Weather-forecast\images')
        img = Image.open("weather.png")
        smaller_image = img.resize((300,300), Image.LANCZOS)#ANTIALIS
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(smaller_image)
        tk.Label(self, image = img1).grid(column=0, row=0)

class CurrentWeatherFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        current_weather = wp.current_weather()
        place_name,weather_code,temperature,precipitation_probability,windspeed = current_weather[0],current_weather[1], current_weather[2],current_weather[3],current_weather[4]
        tk.Label(self, text=place_name).grid(row=0, column=0)

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        os.chdir(r'C:\Users\milos\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\Weather-forecast\images')
        self.title('Weather forecast')
        self.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        self.geometry('800x600+50+50')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.__create_widgets()
    
    def __create_widgets(self):
        current_weather_frame = CurrentWeatherFrame(self)
        current_weather_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        image_frame = ImageFrame(self)
        image_frame.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky='e')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app1 = app()
   app1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subtle bug in tkinter.  `tk.Label` does not grab a reference to the `PhotoImage`, so when `__create_widgets` ends, the photo is deleted.  Just use `self.img1` instead of `img1`.